# Explorer or sailor finds life-like stone sculptures of humans in a cave (Medusa's?) by the sea

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I *think* that this was a short story. I remember reading it as a kid in the 1970s. It was a modern tale with an explorer or sailor of some sort who found himself in a cave near the sea and discovered a bunch of life-like stone sculptures of humans. I think the implication is that he was in Medusa's cave, but I don't recall how the story turned out or if he escaped. Any ideas? Chances are that it was part of a book collection. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be "Island of Fear" by William Sambrot, as in this old question and answer? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193530/trying-to-remember-name-of-an-eerie-story-about-a-seemingly-uninhabited-greek-is

Comment: Sambrot's "Island of Fear" is in the hardcover edition of *Alfred Hitchcock Presents: My Favorites in Suspense*, which can be borrowed from the Internet Archive, though registration is required. https://archive.org/details/myfavoratesinsus0000unse

Comment: @LogicDictates According to the rules of this site, we don't close story-identification requests as duplicates unless the OP accepts the identification. The theory is that only the OP is in a position to say whether an answer to such a question is correct. I think "Island of Fear" is probably the right answer but it's not a 100% match to the OP's description: the life-like statues are not in a cave.

Comment: There's a story "The Gorgon's Guests" by John H. Knox which has an evil scientist create a poison gas that causes people's tissues to turn hard like stone.  The "statues" (victims) are in a cave in that case, but it's more of a detective thriller since it's not supernatural.  (Even though the gas is clearly beyond science it's still counted as non-genre for some reason.)

Comment: @user14111 - I really just wanted to flag the question as a possible duplicate to draw attention to it, but it didn't give me the option of doing that without also voting to close.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Just putting the link in the comments makes it a Linked answer.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Sambrot's story is close, but it doesn't feel quite right. I can't shake the feeling that the moment of realization took place in a cave.

Comment: @jim Do you think the story was supernatural? It wasn't a mad scientist turning people into stone with sci-fi chemicals as in the story suggested in DavidW's comment?

Comment: No, I don't think chemicals. I recall the protagonist's dawning realization that he was in a gorgon's lair, and how uneasy that made me, as a young reader, feel. I'm not even sure that the gorgon appears in the story. Just this sudden awareness that this part of the myth, at least, was true.